# ASP.Net jQuery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the following references of jQuery but unable figure out what files are conflicting, I am trying to use jQuery plugins to implement an event calendar.

If someone can point out what I am doing wrong it would be a great help. Thanks in advance.   :

```
<link href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" 
  type="text/css" />
<link href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
/>

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="jquery/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="scripts/calendarscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-0.6.2.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Default.aspx:469)
    at Function.<anonymous> (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
```

script part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= this.addCustomer.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var param = { keyword: $("#<%= this.addCustomer.ClientID%>").val() };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Default.aspx/getCustomersName",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split(" ")[0],
                                    val: item.split(" ")[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {

                        $("#<%=this.addCustomer.ClientID%>").val(ui.item.label+ui.item.val)
                        $("#<%=this.hfCustomerId.ClientID%>").val(ui.item.val)

                    }
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
```

Comment: $("#<%= this.addCustomer.ClientID%>") is it correct element name??

Comment: @Sameer yes it's fine cause it was working till I integrated the calendar.

Comment: You are using custom jquery ui seems autocomplete component is missing, `jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js`

Comment: What version should I use instead of this..?

Comment: @MehrozIrshad you can build your own download containing the components you require, from the jQueryUI website. Or find a hosted CDN version of the entire library, there are plenty.